# Server uptime in Ktor

Tags: node.js, kotlin, monitoring, ktor, ktor-client

How do I calculate server uptime in Ktor. In nodejs, there is process.uptime() which returns server uptime. I don't see an equivalent method in Ktor. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Import:**

```
import kotlin.time.toDuration
import kotlin.time.DurationUnit
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory
```

You can try with [ManagementFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/RuntimeMXBean.html) api to get uptime of current running process and convert into duration like below.

```
routing {
    get("/") {
        val millis = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().uptime
        val duration = millis.toDuration(DurationUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        call.respond(duration.toString())
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: `import kotlin.time.toDuration`

I think its not deprecated. 
Have you added correct import?